# Issue with using MAX()

Tags: mysql

I was answering a question on SO that encountered this issue.

Why I can't use `MAX()` within a `LIMIT`?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, MAX(id)
```

Or

```
SELECT *, MAX(id) AS m
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, m
```

Both give a similar syntax error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(id)' at line 4
```

*Wanted query:*

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, MAX(id)-5
```

Comment: Because MAX - is aggregate function, which should use in SELECT block and with GROUP BY construction - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Why do you want to use `max(id)` on `limit`? just take out the limit clause.

Comment: @JorgeCampos that's simplified. it's because I wanna do a subtraction on MAX(id) number later.

Comment: So @SashiKant answer will do the trick.

Comment: @yAnTar so why the second query gives an error too?

Comment: Please write situation to the question - which you have. I think - we can create query in another way (without MAX in LIMIT construction).

Comment: Describe your situation by the words - for examle I need get all rows from db without 5 last

Comment: You can use the HAVING clause with MAX(id) to obtain your desired result. Check my answer below

Comment: @revo My mistake......corrected the query.....the order of order by and having was wrong. Updated the answer. Check it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX()` is an aggregate function over the result rows, but `LIMIT` is a clause that constrains the number of result rows.  In short, you cannot use a function that depends on the result rows while you are still determining which rows will be in the result -- that simply doesn't make any sense.

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), `LIMIT` arguments must either be integer constants *or* parameters of a prepared query (emphasis mine):

> `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, **which must both be nonnegative integer constants** (except when using prepared statements).

The syntax specification simply does not allow a column or function to be used.  You would have to pre-compute the value and then use it in a prepared query (or by string substitution, though I would avoid that).

---

Based on the query you gave in your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, MAX(id)-5
```

I suspect that this is the query you actually want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table) - 5
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Even if it were valid, the first query you gave will not do what you expect if there are gaps in the sequence of the `id` column (for example, if a row was deleted).

Comment: would you say then what's wrong with my second query? has the same reason?

Comment: @revo Yes. You are trying to use the result set in order to filter what is in the result set.  In other words, you use the result before the result is known.

Comment: So how can I achieve the results I want from the last query [3rd one]?

Comment: @revo It's hard to tell exactly what you want, since I don't think you quite understand what `LIMIT` does, but see the addition I made to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you want to get your desired result is to create a dynamic sql.

```
SET @maxID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableName);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT *
                   FROM tableName
                   ORDER BY ID DESC
                   LIMIT 0,', @maxID);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Actually I'm zero at dynamic SQL but that doesn't mean I don't like new ways! tnx

Comment: may I ask one question about your query?

Comment: why changing last `@maxID` to `@maxID-5` or `MAX(ID)` to `MAX(ID)-5` doesn't affect the results?!

Answer (score 1):

The function MAX cannot be used on the limit.

Here is the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

The count argument in the limit should be a value so you cannot execute that in one step. Here is the select documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

You can do is:

```
SET @a=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table);
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @a;
```

So it is a tree step here. Get max in a variable. Prepare a statement and than execute it applying the variable to the statement.

Comment: If I could accept more than one answers, I would have gone for three!

Comment: may I ask one question about your query?

Comment: Yes. What is the question?

Comment: why changing `?` to `?-5` or `MAX(ID)` to `MAX(ID)-5` doesn't affect the results?!

Comment: If you user ?-5 on the PREPARE STATEMENT mysql will throw a syntax error. This is possible: SET @a=(SELECT (MAX(ID)-5) FROM table);. This is not possible EXECUTE STMT USING @a-5;. In the last case I even tried to add parenthesis and mysql returned a syntax error. Another option is: set @a := @a-5;.

Comment: I did both ways 1-`SET @a=(SELECT (MAX(ID)-5) FROM table);` 2-`set @a := @a-5;` but every time all rows are fetched!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HAVING clause with MAX(id) to obtain your desired result

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
HAVING id<((SELECT Max(id) FROM table1)-5)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16e50/3

Comment: good point, but yet same error `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING id<MAX(id)-5' at line 4`

Comment: @revo I have corrected the query and checked it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab67a/1

Comment: yes, that doesn't give any error but result contains one row only!

Comment: @revo Updated the query again and fiddle link is also there in answer. It is giving 2 rows now when table has 8 rows

Comment: +1 yes that works! and also if you want to know, this query lasts  2.891s on a table with 575 rows and 21 columns!

Comment: @revo You can replace Max with count in the above query if you want to fetch all rows apart from last 5 rows. See if the change improves performance

Answer (score -1):

ISSUE IS WIth your query::

```
Select 
* 
from
myTable,
(SELECT MAX(id) as n
FROM table) temp
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, temp.n
```

Comment: -1 Did you actually try this?  `You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near 'temp.n'`.

Comment: I didn't vote on your answer yet, but yes the error still remains.